# Nested states with parent's url == /

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I have the following state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state( 'home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'dashboard-body': {
                templateUrl: './modules/main-dashboard.options.html',
                controller: 'MainDashboardController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    } );
```

Can it have nested states?... I'm having trouble with it, I have the following states:

```
$stateProvider
    .state( 'home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'dashboard-body': {
                templateUrl: './modules/main-dashboard.options.html',
                controller: 'MainDashboardController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    } )
    .state( 'home.purchases', {
        url: '/purchases',
        views: {
            'dashboard-body@home': {
                templateUrl: './modules/purchases/purchases-dashboard.options.html',
                controller: 'PurchasesDashboardController',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    } );
```

But if i go to `home.purchases` state the url generated is: `http://localhost:3000//purchases`

If `home.purchases` has the property url like: `url: 'purchases'`, it generates the right url `http://localhost:3000/purchases` but it doesnt't change the view... Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing your `home` state URL to `url: ''`. Also, does your home state template include a nested `ui-view="dashboard-body"`? If it doesn't, your *purchases* state view should be `'dashboard-body@'`

Comment: It worked with the `'dashboard-body@'`!! Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your root view (typically `index.html`) has the element with

```
ui-view="dashboard-body"
```

then your `home.purchases` state needs to reference that view using

```
views: {
    'dashboard-body@': {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise, it's trying to load the template into a view named `dashboard-body` within the `home` state's template (`modules/main-dashboard.options.html`)